# SQL Request if criteria is not null

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to write a query that performs a search according to several criteria.

My current JPA request:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Client c " +
    "INNER JOIN c.entite e " +
    "WHERE e.numeroLicence in (:numerosLicence) " +
    "AND (UPPER(c.nom) LIKE CONCAT('%',UPPER(:nom),'%') " +
    "AND (c.prenom IS NOT NULL AND UPPER(c.prenom) LIKE CONCAT('%',UPPER(:prenom),'%')) " +
    "AND (c.dateCreation IS NOT NULL AND c.dateCreation > :dateCreation) " +
    "AND (c.dateCreation IS NOT NULL AND c.dateModification > :dateModification) " +
    "AND (c.dateCreation IS NOT NULL AND c.dateSuppression > :dateSuppression)) ")
Page<Client> recherche(@Param("numerosLicence") ArrayList numerosLicence,
                       @Param("nom") String nom,
                       @Param("prenom") String prenom,
                       @Param("dateCreation") ZonedDateTime dateCreation,
                       @Param("dateModification") ZonedDateTime dateModification,
                       @Param("dateSuppression") ZonedDateTime dateSuppression,
                       Pageable pageable);
```

The problem is that it automatically excludes rows where a column contains NULL.

I'll need the selection to be done on columns with data only, it will not try to execute the clause if the field value is NULL

For example, if I have a row whose `firstname` column is NULL, then this line is automatically excluded from the result whereas I would like it not to test this column if it is NULL

Do you have an idea?
I'm looking for a solution to avoid creating as many queries as possible combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you should use `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
c.dateCreation IS NULL
   OR c.dateCreation > :dateCreation
```

Comment: No Sorry, result is the same

Comment: Sorry, a typo. Try again.